# After rename package to lower case WELD cannot find class

Tags: java, wildfly, weld

I am using wildfly and I have weird problem. Firstly i had class in package:

1)    `app.service.parkingMeter.ParkingMeterService`

Everything works fine, deploy is ok.

Then i renamed this package to:

2)    `app.service.parkingmeter.ParkingMeterService`

And i got

> WELD-001474: Class app.service.ticket.TicketService is on the classpath, but was
>   ignored because a class it references was not found:
>   app.service.parkingmeter.ParkingMeterService

When i came back to name (1) everything start working again back to (2) same error again. When i moved my class to package:

3) `app.service.test.ParkingMeterService`

No error occurred.

What is the source of this problem and how can i fixed it

Comment: So you renamed the package. Did you ensure all places where said package were referenced were also updated? Including in .xml files that may not be normally refactored by some IDEs?

Comment: That's right, but even if something wasn't renamed in .xml files so why renamed to (`app.service.test.ParkingMeterService`) works fine

Comment: What operating system are you running?  The change of case may not have been noticeable on standard Mac OS/X and Windows.

Comment: Windows 7, so this is probably reason?, but how can i move my class from package `parkingMeter` to `parkingmeter` and make my application to work. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes - move it to test.  Then move it to the new name.  Those are both total name changes that the O/S and the IDE will recognize.